# How to configure reverse proxy rules for gitlab on nodejs express

Tags: node.js, apache, express, gitlab, reverse-proxy

I'm currently developing nodejs application to serve private gitlab server. I got it working with Apache, but now I wan't to replace Apache with Nodejs application. I got it almost working.

Website is working properly, I can see my projects etc.

When I try to clone repository like this

```
git clone http://example.com:3000/apps/test.git
```

It will clone empty repository, and gives this

```
Cloning into 'test'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Repository is not empty. It work's when I clone it using Apache

**app.js**

```
let express = require('express'),
    app = express(),

    PORT = process.env.PORT||3000

    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    path = require('path'),
    HttpProxyRules = require('http-proxy-rules'),
    proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer()


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let targetUri= `http://localhost:8181${req.url}`
    let targetUri2= `http://localhost:8080${req.url}`

    let proxyRules = new HttpProxyRules({
        rules: {
            '/[\\w\.-]+/[\\w\.-]+/repository/archive.*': targetUri,
            '/api/v3/projects/.*/repository/archive.*': targetUri,
            '/[\\w\.-]+/[\\w\.-]+/(info/refs|git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)$': targetUri,
            '/uploads': targetUri2
        },
        default: 'http://localhost:8080'

        let proxy = new httpProxy.createProxy()
        let target = proxyRules.match(req)

        if(target)
            return proxy.web(req, res { target }

    })
})
console.log(`Listening port ${PORT}`)
app.listen(PORT)
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "http-proxy": "^1.13.2",
    "http-proxy-rules": "^1.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found working resolution for rules.

```
let targetUri = `http://localhost:8181${req.url}`

let proxyRules = new HttpProxyRules({
    rules: {
        '/api/v3/.*': targetUri,
        '/uploads': targetUri
    },
    default: 'http://localhost:8181'
})
```